# Randomly select a window from a 3D array using Tensorflow Queue

Tags: tensorflow

I have a 3D numpy array data set `AxBxC`. How can I apply the Tensorflow `RandomShuffleQueue` to implement the random selection (`dequeue` or `dequeue_many`) with window size `axbxC` over the first two dimension of the data set?

```
A = 500
B = 600
C = 400
data = np.random.rand(A, B, C)
q. tf.RandomShuffleQueue(capacity=???, shapes=???)
```

I want to use Queue instead of `tf.random_crop` to reduce the overhead of CPU-GPU communication incurred by `placeholder`.